# How to use infer keyword to get the type passed as argument to a generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to use the `infer` keyword to retrieve the type that was used as argument on a generic.

similar to:

```
type ArrayElementType<T> = T extends Array<infer E> ? E : T;
type Element = ArrayElementType<Array<number>> // gives number on type element
```

But in my case I want to do something like:

```
// Pluggable is just an example, my actual use case makes the type extends something bigger, but I don't think it matters
type Pluggable<T> = T & { disabled?: boolean }
type PluggableElementType<T> = T extends Pluggable<infer E> ? E : never;

type Element= PluggableElementType<Pluggable<{prop: number}>>
// I want Element to be {prop: number} but instead i'm getting {prop:number} & {disabled?: boolean}
```

I don't know if I'm in the right path, but I think it's clear what I want to achieve. Maybe it's necessary to modify de Pluggable type? I don't know what makes the Array interface works, is it just because it's an interface instead of a type intersection?

Comment: That's the widest possible type that could be given to `Pluggable` and produce the same result. If you don't want this, then maybe filter out `{ disabled?: boolean }` from the result in `PluggableElementType`.

Comment: Thanks for you fast comment. By filtering you mean something like Omit<T, 'disabled'>? If yes, It would work in this case with fewer keys, but in my actual use case that my grow. Isn't there any other way to grab the original type used as argument on a generic?

Comment: You could use `Omit<T, keyof Pluggable<{}>>` if you are concerned about maintenance, and no way to get the original argument that I know of.

Comment: To follow the same pattern as `ArrayElementType<T>` would it be `type PluggableElementType<T> = T extends Pluggable<infer E> ? E : T;` (with `T` instead of `never`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, but unfortunately both results in the same.

Comment: @kelly Yeah, I was thinking about that after I commented. So it won't work because it will always infer the result of that generic right? If you want to post as the answer I'll accept it for now

Comment: I am getting `{prop: number}`. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wzea1m)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine True, don't know what's going on, when I posted I swear the result was different, I just tried locally again and could not reproduce the behavior, it will always give me `prop: number` wich is what I want so I'm not complaining but damn I'm confused. BTW you think the same could be achieved by using a union instead of intersection? e.g `Pluggable<T> = T | {disabled: true} `

Comment: @MarcoMoura just give a try. If you are able to reproduce the error I will try to do my best to help you